# Can execute permission in a php file cause any havoc or problems?

Tags: php, permissions

I have a database that hosts three different sites. Most files on one have permissions 644, most on the other two have 755, which as I have learnt includes the execute permission. I was wondering if that could cause any problems (not because I want to avoid changing it, just because there are a few problems on one of the site that has execute permissions and I don't know if this could have caused it). I know execute permissions are not strictly speaking necessary for php files but I don't know why, so I don't know if they do anything... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you execute php scripts. It your scripts are shellscript or executed via cgi your php scripts need the execution bit. If you are running via webserver and mod_php then this is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To add to tonymarschall's answer, a file is either executable or it is not. The scope of havoc arises when one executes the script as a privileged user. Usually, a script executes as the same user as the server unless some suid bits are sets (Linux now recognizes suid bits only on binaries and not ASCII text scripts). If the scripts happen to run as root and get exploited, the damage is far more than if they were exploited as a regular user.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info! I'd have chosen both as correct answers if I could, both helped me figure it out :)